# Rates and Ratio work problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ratio

I've encountered this problem

> It takes $60$ minutes for $7$ people to paint $5$ walls. How many minutes does it take $10$ people to paint $10$ walls.

The answer to this one is $84$ minutes. However, How did it come up to this answer? can someone explain to me why?

Can anyone give a step by step method on how did we lead to this/solve this kind of problems?

Comment: Off-topic: How long are the original $7$ people given to gen in the $3$ new apprentices?  My guess would be a total of $3$ hours for $10$ walls: Two hours for the original $7$ people to paint all the walls, plus one hour of training time (during which time there is only negligible progress on the actual walls.)  ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are given that:

> It takes 60 minutes for 7 people to paint 5 walls.

**Consider:** Rate $\times$ Time $=$ Output.

Let us consider "Rate" to mean the rate at which **one person** works.

And rather than writing out the whole word, let us just write $R$.

In the given: $7R \times 60$ minutes $=$ $5$ walls.

Omitting units and rearranging, we have: $7R = 5/60 = 1/12$.

Dividing both sides by $7$, we get $R = 1/84$.

Then you ask:

> How many minutes does it take 10 people to paint 10 walls?

Set up similarly, we have: $10R \times t$ minutes $= 10$ walls.

Dividing both sides by $10$ and omitting units, we have: $R \times t = 1$.

But we know $R = 1/84$, so this says: $t/84 = 1$.

To finish off matters, multiply both sides by $84$ to obtain: $t = 84$.

It takes **eighty four minutes**.

---

Here is an alternative approach, just for fun. Omitting units throughout:

In both scenarios, the **rate** of work is the same; we will use this to solve the problem.

**Note:** Rate $=$ Output $\div$ Time.

In scenario one, the rate of one person working is: $5/(60\cdot 7).$

In scenario two, the rate of one person working is: $10/(t\cdot 10).$

We need to solve for $t$, but these expressions are equal. Let us simplify the resulting equation:

$$\frac{5}{60 \cdot 7} = \frac{10}{t \cdot 10} \implies \frac{1}{12 \cdot 7} = \frac{1}{t}$$

Equating denominators (or "cross multiplying") we find $t = 12 \cdot 7 = 84$.

Comment: Hmm. Almost got the same result as you but how did you lead up to   7R=5/60=1/127R=5/60=1/12.?

Comment: @KyelJmD From 7R x 60 = 5, you can divide both sides by 60. This gives: 7R = 5/60, and you can simplify the fraction 5/60 to become 1/12. And so you end up with: 7R = 1/12. If you want R on its own, the next step is to divide both sides by 7. Then you have: R = 1/84.

Comment: I see, What topic should I look into for that one? I might have forgotten that one already. I was treating it as a Linear Equation. I ended up with 7R = 5 + 60. Which is wrong.

Comment: Ohh.  Linear equation using the division property, perhaps?

Answer (score 6):

There is a formula you may find useful:

If it takes time $T_1$ for $X_1$ people to do $Y_1$ things, and time $T_2$ for $X_2$ people to do $Y_2$ things, then
$$\boxed{\frac{X_1T_1}{Y_1}\ =\ \frac{X_2T_2}{Y_2}}$$
In this particular problem, $T_1=60$, $X_1=7$, $Y_1=5$, $X_2=10$, $Y_2=10$; substituting in the formula gives $T_2=84$.

Proof of the formula:

If $X_1$ people can do $Y_1$ things, then 1 person can do $\dfrac{Y_1}{X_1}$ things in the same time, and so $X_2$ people can do $\dfrac{X_2Y_1}{X_1}$ in this time. Say, this time is $T_1$. Then in time 1, the same number of people $X_2$ can do $\dfrac{X_2Y_1}{X_1T_1}$ things so in time $T_2$ they can do $\dfrac{X_2Y_1T_2}{X_1T_1}$ things. Hence
$$Y_2\ =\ \dfrac{X_2Y_1T_2}{X_1T_1}$$
which can be rearranged to the formula above.

Comment: (The formula you have written out here, if one inverts both sides, is the method used in the "alternative" answer I provided.)

Comment: What math lecture can I review for that formula? or formula derivation?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a similar problem. You can look at this then work out yours.

**Question:**
It takes 42 minutes for 7 people to paint 6 walls. How many minutes does it take 8 people to paint 8 walls?

**Solution:**
It takes 42 minutes for 7 people to paint 6  walls
42/6=7 minutes per wall

It takes 7 people 7 minutes  to paint 1 wall

Each person paints 1/7 of the wall in 7 minutes

Each person paints 1/49 of the wall in 1 minute at the same rate...

8 people paint 8/49 of 1 wall in 1 minute

How many minutes does it take 8 people to paint 1 wall ?
49/8=6 1/8

It takes 8 people 6 1/8 minutes to paint 1 wall

It takes 8 people 8*(6 1/8) minutes to paint 8 walls

8*(6 1/8)=49 minutes

It takes 49 minutes for 8 people to paint 8 walls

Comment: There is a thing in grammar called the period, and it makes things more clear.

Comment: Fair call.... :)

Comment: I have question how did we lead up to this? "Each person paints 1/49 of the wall in 1 minute at the same rate..." How did the 49 and 1 minute came up?

Comment: Since one person paints 1/7th of the wall in 7 minutes, in 1 minute, its 1/7 divided by 7. Also, I suggest you show what working out you've done instead of looking for an answer like one below

Answer (score 2):

Seven people working for 60 minutes amounts to a total of 420 minutes of work to paint 5 walls.

So one wall takes $\frac{420}{5}=84$ minutes of work to paint.

So 10 walls requires 840 minutes to paint. And if you have 10 people working together, that comes to 84 minutes each.

Answer (score 1):

Exploit linear dependence.

You have a relation between a number P of persons, a number M of minutes and a number W of walls painted. You know that P=7, M=60 gives W=5 and you are asked what is M such that P=10 gives W=10. So you should move from P=7 to P=10 and from W=5 to W=10 and keep track of the changes of M.

What happens if you double the number of people P and keep the same amount of time M? Of course, the walls painted W gets doubled. The same is true if you multiply P by any number k: W gets multiplied by the same number. So from P=7, M=60, W=5 you multiply both P and W by 10/7 and find P=10, M=60, W=(10/7)5=50/7.

Now what happens if you double the time M keeping P fixed? Of course the number of walls painted W also doubles. The same is true if you multiply M by any number, you get W multiplied by the same number. You need to find anumber k such that W goes from 50/7 to 10, so (50/7)k=10 which means k=(7/50)10 = 7/5. The time M then goes from 60 to (7/5)60 which is 84.

Answer (score 1):

These problems are not difficult to solve in your head, even without an explicit algebraic formula:

> It takes $60$
>    minutes for $7$
>    people to paint $5$
>    walls. How many minutes does it take $10$
>    people to paint $10$
>    walls?

Original time: $60$ minutes.

Double the count of walls from $5$ to $10$ -> double the time to $120$ minutes.

Pretend only $1$ person instead of the current $7$ -> multiply the time by $7$.

($7\times120 = 840$ minutes.)

Now with $10$ times as many people ($10$ instead of $1$), it will take a tenth of that amount of time, which is $84$ minutes.

---

Of course I advise you to understand the formula.  This method *is* the exact same steps as you will take by computing the formula algebraically, but I have found students who trip on the algebraic manipulation of variables are able to pick up this approach quite easily, and *then* become able to make sense of the algebra when they couldn't before.  Hence I feel it is a valuable approach worth mentioning.

The "formula" is, of course, that "walls per person per minute" is a constant value.

---

Actually *answering* such questions, I factually don't use any "method" personally as the calculations are done too fast to illustrate, whether through formulas or sentences.  How do you answer the question, "What is $5+5$?"  If you actually count $5$ and then $5$ more I feel bad for you.  But, steps *can* be illustrated and followed through until you achieve the ability to just instantly state the answer.